# Custom post type adds time/date and author to the post?

Tags: customization

I got a custom post type, which for some reason adds a line to the post itself (checked the database).
The line looks like this:

```
1 sep. 2019 kl. 21:05 skrev Sitename :
```

The weird part is my site is set to English, not Swedish, and the added line is in Swedish.
I did a search in the plugin and it is not hardcoded to add it in Swedish, and I cannot find out where this line is.

The plugin is no longer active so I cannot ask the author of the plugin.

I have tried searching for `get_the_time`, `get_the_date` and `get_the_author` without finding the line I am searching for!

Any ideas what to look for?
I really want to get rid of this line.